# How can I insert on Google Sheets an item price from Amazon?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to insert from this **link**:

https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07NDW5NSW/ref=twister_B07P9DXZ1C?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

the current **price** of the smartphone, that at the moment is:

[image: photo of Amazon price] (853).

I tried with this **formula**:

```
=importXml("https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07NDW5NSW/ref=twister_B07P9DXZ1C?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1";"//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")
```

but the result, as you can see in the foto, is

> `#N/A`, the imported content is empty

[image: N/A]

Do you have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not doable the way you are trying. Amazon implemented anti-scraping measurements so the only way is to use their API:

> For automated access to price change or offer listing change events
>   please refer to the MWS Subscription API:
>   https://developer.amazonservices.it/gp/mws/api.html/277-5993977-7749460?ie=UTF8&section=subscriptions&group=subscriptions&version=latest

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
=importxml(hyperlink(concatenate("https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07NDW5NSW")),"//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")
```